# Is it possible to open another application inside Container Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I can open another app with

```
DeviceApps.openApp('com.android.camera')
```

But I want to put it inside container,is there some way to do this?Maybe I have to use some plugin
like "flutter_webview"?

````
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DeviceApps.openApp('com.android.camera');
    return 
Center(child:
  Container(
    width:300,
    height:400
    


    ));


          ```
````

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer to this is no, you cannot do this!

The reason behind that is that applications both on iOS an Android run inside something called a sandbox. This is the same model that macOS also uses. This means that each application only knows about itself and the data that it saves, unless on a shared location, cannot be used or accessed by another application.